# Looking for website for watching Dropbox/Google Drive videos online

Tags: google-drive, dropbox, video, video-streaming

I want to watch videos with my friends together. Usually we create Zoom conference and just click "Start" on the video simultaneously.

The problem is we usually watch our selfmade videos which we cannot upload on YouTube and Vimeo because of copyright issues (I've tried and got my videos banned). Uploading the video on Dropbox/Google Drive solves this problem, but I couldn't find any website similar to [Watch2gether](https://watch2gether.com) which supports streaming from any cloud drive.

Is there any website that supports cloud drives?

Comment: Is it legal for you to have copies of your "selfmade" videos?

Comment: Why is it not possible to watch the video locally? The file can be synced onto your computer's hard drive. Secondly, do you realise that you can play a video in the Google Drive web app?

Comment: @ahorn The problem is I need to set the pause for example or skip a fragment simultaneously on all devices.

Comment: @ahorn Yes, it is legal content.

Comment: Questions that asks for software recommendation are off-topic in this site. Try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of alternatives for you.

[Cytu.be](https://cytu.be/) and [Rave.io](https://rave.io/)

**They both support Google Drive**.
One of their main differences is that [rave.io](https://rave.io/) is only available on  iOS and Android.

**Some of the key features that may interest you are *(as found in their official websites)***:

---

**1. [Cytu.be](https://cytu.be/)**

[How do I pause or seek the video?](https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-pause-or-seek-the-video)
CyTube controls the video playback with a timer on the server in order to provide smooth playback and prevent accidental clicks by channel moderators from interrupting the video for other people. However, if you need to control the video, you can right click your name in the userlist and click "Give Leader". While you are leader, you will be able to pause/unpause and seek the video. When you're done, right click your name again and click "Take Leader".

[How do I enable subtitles on Google Drive videos?](https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-enable-subtitles-on-google-drive-videos)
As of July 28th, 2015, it is now possible to use Google Drive subtitles on CyTube. Please see here for instructions on adding subtitles to your Google Drive videos.

[Google Drive Userscript Installation Guide](https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/wiki/Google-Drive-Userscript-Installation-Guide)

---

**2. [Rave.io](https://rave.io/)**

What does Rave do?
Rave is the purest form of social media. We help people come together around content they love on tablet and mobile, perfectly synchronizing videos while talking and texting. Rave has recently expanded from shared viewing to creating new content, with RaveDJ, the world's first AI DJ, capable of autonomously composing seamless mashups from user-selected songs.

What can I watch on Rave?
Rave features content from YouTube, Vimeo, Reddit, Google Drive, Dropbox, and Viki.

Who can I use Rave with?
Invite some friends, or start a public rave and make a new friend. Rave has users in almost every country in the world, so you never know who you're going to meet.

Text or chat by voice while enjoying content from YouTube, Netflix, Vimeo, Reddit, Google Drive, and more! Come together for a international movie night, or combine your phones to create an instant speaker system!

Answer (score 0):

There is a app xplorer file manager for android and for android tv and it support streaming from drive or any other cloud storage. By default the app only stream the video but in menu in configuration unselect video option then when you u play video this app will ask for video player in which you want to stream. I have downloaded vlc and I select vlc always. You need to set up your cloud information first to stream.In web storage click on add server.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Koi Watch](https://koiwatch.netlify.app) is a watch together web app that has Google Drive support. (Disclaimer: I built Koi Watch. Like yourself, I was searching for options and built Koi Watch to meet my needs).

Answer (score -1):

While I have not found a video platform like the one you are talking about, I have found that streaming or screen sharing the screen and playing the video will have the same effect. Personally I use discord for this, or you could use zoom. It also has the side effect of eliminating the issue of having to upload it seeing as one will be streaming the video to the other.